# How could I make the moment.Moment to be in UTC, but preserve the date and time?

Tags: javascript, time, timezone, momentjs, utc

How could I make the `moment.Moment` to be in UTC, but preserve the date and time?

E.g. I have the `moment.Moment` which holds a non UTC time:

`Tue Sep 14 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)`

I want to have a `moment.Moment` which would have the same time, i.e. `Tue Sep 14 2021 00:00:00`, but in UTC.

Comment: What's the connection between those two times then? That's basically an arbitrarily different time. Why is the first timestamp not in UTC to begin with if apparently you want it to be?

Comment: @deceze, I have some controls (Angular components, if it matters), they have some functionality which I can not modify, which gives out datetime in browser specific format. This is ok, but I want to treat that time as UTC on backend, so I try to change it before sending. Is it a bad approach? Should I try something different? :)

Comment: @deceze, meaning that if I have `Tue Sep 14 2021 00:00:00` on frontend I want to see the same time on backend. But due to UTC conversion I am getting a different time on backend.

Comment: Is the user *expecting* to be inputting localised time, or UTC time? If the user thinks they're selecting UTC time when they select, say, "2am", but the control gives you "2am CEST", then okay, you need to extract the "2am" part and construct a UTC time with it. But if the user expects the selected "2am" means "2am CEST", then to treat that as UTC on the backend you need to properly *convert* the timezone so "2am CEST" becomes "0am UTC".

Comment: @deceze, there are records of some data. Users want to be able to filter out those records by datetime (by providing start and end datetimes). I assume in this case users do not care about timezone. But unfortunately I can not update the components code.

Comment: Well, timezones *mean* something… Querying for records matching 2am UTC will yield different results than querying for records matching 2am CEST. It's perfectly valid to store records with UTC time, and to let users query using their local time. I.e., user selects 2am CEST and sees records for 0am UTC → perfectly valid and user friendly in fact.